# Convert python string "['a', 'b']" to list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a form that save lists as strings, I want to convert those strings to lists before save in DB.

I'm using python3 and Django.

The strings looks like:
`'["MEX","MTY","GDL","BJX","QRO","PBC","TLC","CUN","EM","CUU"]'`

what will be the most pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

json.loads('["MEX","MTY","GDL","BJX","QRO","PBC","TLC","CUN","EM","CUU"]')
```